# jQuery not initializing with jQuery Mobile after page refresh

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I know there are lots of Q&A's on triggering to refresh content in jQuery Mobile, I've read most of them, but I  cannot get the dragend.js to initialize after a page refresh on a secondary page.

menu.php is a Swipe Menu using dragend.js. Everything works. If i navigate to page 2 and then back to the menu, everything still works. If I navigate to page 2 and then refresh that page and then navigate to the menu, the Swipe script fails.

Any help glady appreciated.

**menu.php**

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jqm.css" />
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function() {
$.mobile.page.prototype.options.domCache = true;
});
</script>

<script src="js/jqm.js"></script>

<script src="js/dragend.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).on("pagecontainershow", function() {
var BODY = $("body"),
container = $("#swipe"),
pageElements;
$(window).on("ready resize", function(event) {
var width = $(this).width(),
itemsInPage = 1;
if (width > 300) {
itemsInPage = 4
}
container.dragend({
pageContainer: "#container",
itemsInPage: itemsInPage,
pageClass: "item",
afterInitialize: function() {
this.container.style.visibility = "visible";
}});
});
});
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div data-role="page" id="menu">
<div data-role="content">

<ul id="swipe">
<li class="item"><a href="#" id="item1">Link one</a></li>
<li class="item"><a href="#" id="item2">Link two</a></li>
<li class="item"><a href="#" id="item3">Link three</a></li>
<li class="item"><a href="#" id="item4">Link four</a></li>
<li class="item"><a href="#" id="item5">Link five</a></li>
<li class="item"><a href="#" id="item6">Link six</a></li>
<li class="item"><a href="#" id="item7">Link seven</a></li>
<li class="item"><a href="#" id="item8">Link eight</a></li>
<li class="item"><a href="#" id="item9">Link nine</a></li>
</ul>

</div>
</div>
</body>
```

**page2.php**

```
head as above

<body>

<div data-role="page" id="another-page">
<div data-role="content">

Another page content.

<a href="menu.php">Menu</a>

</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: I haven't used JQuery.Mobile in awhile, but isn't there an "updateLayout" event?  If that doesn't work, I believe you can manually trigger initializing the page.  Sorry ...my memory is foggy here.

Comment: Thanks. I tried the updateLayout trigger and it didn't work. I'm sure that is the correct way of doing it so i must be adding the code wrong.